# Matplotlib: Don't show errorbars in legend

Tags: matplotlib

I'm plotting a series of data points with x and y error but do NOT want the errorbars to be included in the legend (only the marker). Is there a way to do so?

[image: How to avoid errorbars in legend?]

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
subs=['one','two','three']
x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,2,3]
yerr=[2,3,1]
xerr=[0.5,1,1]
fig,(ax1)=plt.subplots(1,1)
for i in np.arange(len(x)):
    ax1.errorbar(x[i],y[i],yerr=yerr[i],xerr=xerr[i],label=subs[i],ecolor='black',marker='o',ls='')
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', numpoints=1)
fig.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches=0)
```

Comment: A hack would be to plot the points separately using `plot` and use them in legend.

Comment: Thanks. That works and seems to be the easiest solution. Can't find any option to toggle this behavior. I guess otherwise one would have to alter the handles before passing them to the legend which does not seem easier than consecutively calling errobar / plot.

Comment: If you think this is a useful feature, I suggest you start an issue on github.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can modify the legend handler. See the [legend guide of matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).
Adapting your example, this could read:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

subs=['one','two','three']
x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,2,3]
yerr=[2,3,1]
xerr=[0.5,1,1]
fig,(ax1)=plt.subplots(1,1)

for i in np.arange(len(x)):
    ax1.errorbar(x[i],y[i],yerr=yerr[i],xerr=xerr[i],label=subs[i],ecolor='black',marker='o',ls='')

# get handles
handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
# remove the errorbars
handles = [h[0] for h in handles]
# use them in the legend
ax1.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper left',numpoints=1)


plt.show()
```

This produces

[image: output image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an ugly patch:

```
pp = []
colors = ['r', 'b', 'g']
for i, (y, yerr) in enumerate(zip(ys, yerrs)):
    p = plt.plot(x, y, '-', color='%s' % colors[i])
    pp.append(p[0])
    plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr, color='%s' % colors[i])  
plt.legend(pp, labels, numpoints=1)
```

Here is a figure for example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution works in simple cases but not in general. In particular, it did not work in my own more complex situation.

I found a more robust solution, which tests for `ErrorbarContainer`, which did work for me. It was proposed by [Stuart W D Grieve](https://swdg.io/2015/errorbar-legends/) and I copy it here for completeness

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import container

label = ['one', 'two', 'three']
color = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
yerr = [2, 3, 1]
xerr = [0.5, 1, 1]

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1)

for i in range(len(x)):
    ax1.errorbar(x[i], y[i], yerr=yerr[i], xerr=xerr[i], label=label[i], color=color[i], ecolor='black', marker='o', ls='')

handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [h[0] if isinstance(h, container.ErrorbarContainer) else h for h in handles]

ax1.legend(handles, labels)

plt.show()
```

It produces the following plot (on Matplotlib 3.1)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I works for me if I set the label argument as a None type.

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr, label=None)
```

Comment: This produces no legend at all. A minimal working example, and the resulting output, would help to clarify what you mean.