# Error bars in the legend.

Tags: matplotlib, plot

i'm plotting several data points with y error and I don't want errorbars included in the legend.

```
 p1=ax.errorbar(x,y, yerr=[ydown,yup], color='blue', fmt='s', ecolor='blue')
 p2=ax.errorbar(x1,y1, yerr=[y1down,y1up], color='black', fmt='.', ecolor='black')
 ax.legend([p1,p2],['data1','data2'], loc='upper left', numpoints=1)
```

My question is similar to a previous one:
[Matplotlib: Don't show errorbars in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297714/matplotlib-dont-show-errorbars-in-legend)
but I haven't found solution. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the legend handler. See the [legend guide of matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).
Adapting your example, this could read:

```py
# get handles
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
# remove the errorbars
handles = [h[0] for h in handles]
# use them in the legend
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper left', numpoints=1)
```