# Average point and standard deviation bars on scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

If I have a scatter plot like this MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xlist = []
ylist = []
for i in range(500):
    x = np.random.normal(100)
    xlist.append(x)
    y = np.random.normal(5)
    ylist.append(y)

x_ave = np.average(x)
y_ave = np.average(y)
plt.scatter(xlist, ylist)
plt.scatter(x_ave, y_ave, c = 'red', marker = '*', s = 50)
```

[image]

what's the easiest way to plot the 'average point' (is there a proper word for that?) on the plot? All of the tutorials and examples I've found show how to plot the line of best fit, but I just want the single point.

Plotting `(x_ave, y_ave)` works, but is there a better way, especially since I'd eventually want to show the standard deviations with error bars too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to plot a single scatter point with error bars, the best way would be to use the [`errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) module. The following answer shows an example of using it with customized properties of error bars and the average point with a standard deviation of 1 for both x and y. You can specify your actual standard deviation values in `xerr` and `yerr`. The error bars can be removed from the legend using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551976/4932316) solution.

```
plt.scatter(xlist, ylist)

plt.errorbar(x_ave, y_ave, yerr=1, xerr=1, fmt='*', color='red', ecolor='black', ms=20, 
             elinewidth=4, capsize=10, capthick=4, label='Average')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [h[0] for h in handles]
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='best', fontsize=16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Your solution works, but I get an error:
`handles = [h[0] for h in handles]

TypeError: 'PathCollection' object does not support indexing`
What does this mean?

Comment: @Jim421616: Are you find without these last three lines? If yes, then you can just put `plt.legend()` after `plt.errorbar(...)`. In this case, you will have errorbars too in the legend. I am off to sleep now so will have a look tomorrow if you need the legend without the errorbar. Else, you can try the solutions on the link I posted for legends in my answer and similar other answers on stack overflow